# How can I install PeaZip on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

As the title suggests, how can I install [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/) on Ubuntu 22.04? Is there a preferred way?

Comment: Try: https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-peazip-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: my question is **why is this downvoted with no explanation to why?** up voting it because explanations in my opinion is necessary even if it might be obvious for some who downvotes.

Comment: @WilliamMartens LOL yeah I was wondering why it was downvoted as well?

Comment: @Cool124 yea. This is a often occurrence of nearly all of the sites. please don't get discouraged. (it's easy to get discouraged because of this (and more..) )  but; yes, to me nothing is particularly (that wrong) about the question.

Comment: so, @Cool124 have a nice day, you have done nothing wrong ^_^ as said there is no (relatively speaking) bad questions only bad answers(and bad votes 8) pun intended )

Comment: @WilliamMartens Oh I was never bothered by it lol I have thick skin.

Comment: good. then you are at the correct place at the correct time. :) that reply made my day, as well so thanks!

Comment: Usually you get donwvoted because you don't show a reproducible example or showcase some effort regarding few steps that one mag try. Probably the case here. Asking casually how to achieve a task without a small insight of research can be seen as quite offensive towards answerers who are giving their free time to try to help you out. I didn't donwvoted that one mainly because I'm not an active user of askubuntu but if it was on StackOverflow, I probably would. Then, this thing is also quite personal of course but I do feel that it's justified.

Comment: @kissu Yes, I agree but it's a bit wrong to kind of continue to downvote, because - it's just a question, in the end of the day. but I do agree , **absolutely one should put effort *into the question* As Well as into a downvote.** especially if the user's rep isn't like 100k.

Comment: just a remark on the (offensive* (while I do agree, it's still just, if it's that bad 1 does not need to answ, and downvotes, "can" (and will - sometimes) be just "left there" even if the question is improved, edited, and so on). which is unfair against the question asker who put in time (and rep but that's not really the issue in my opinion) the energy as well; (note this is just my thought, it might(and probably is) wrong, I just try to see it from both sides instead of only 1/half on both ) :) i always try to make posts as constructive as possible, for both sides. Anyway, have a good day u2

Comment: last comment: sometimes the down votes is not really accurate, too. There are people who just looks for ways to spot a error to downvote; and - this one can have different thoughts on, but explaining a downvote is always good, since well, it's a small task  (*NOTE* im not claiming that is the case here, it was just a overall thing)

Comment: @WilliamMartens the downvotes  came before me and kissu [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1446965/revisions) the question and most probably by people who find it opinion-based (though the question didn't have any close votes). The initial question was "what is the **correct** way to install PeaZip?" The term "correct" is what I suspect attracted those downvotes. Obviously, this shouldn't have happened.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog yes okay; thanks for the explanation, +1

Comment: That why an upvote is +10 and downvote is -2 reputation wise. As for the time and effort, the same can be said for an answer. I usually am more fair towards newcomers but that's all. Can be a long subject to discuss anyway. @WilliamMartens

Comment: @kissu Agreed, +1  (I do write much as well), and yes I do know the rep but a newcomer maybe do not, and may be stressed out if downvotes continuing and yea. This is why I am very very rarely downvoting and leaving improvement comment, I **leave comment** first, see if the user tries to edit, or if the user just tells me there's nothing wrong with the question(when it is obvious) then I downvote(or similar) but yes, I agree in general :)  and I do want **to wish a nice week to you and everyone!** before I end this comment;

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no PeaZip package in the default Ubuntu repositories, but there are several ways to install it. Here I will describe the two methods that I think are the easiest and better in my opinion.

**Method 1: Install PeaZip using the prebuilt `.deb` package**

The benefit of this method is that it is a straightforward way to install PeaZip, if you are familiar with software installation in Ubuntu/Linux. The downside is that you'll have to manually repeat the installation procedure to install a new version of PeaZip.

1. Go to the [PeaZip webpage](https://peazip.github.io/) and click [PeaZip for Linux](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-linux.html).
2. Depending on the desktop environment you use (or your personal preference), click either the [DEB GTK2](https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip/releases/download/9.0.0/peazip_9.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-1_amd64.deb) link (suggested for GTK-based environments, such as GNOME, XFCE, Cinnamon, Unity, etc.) or the [DEB Qt5](https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip/releases/download/9.0.0/peazip_9.0.0.LINUX.Qt5-1_amd64.deb) link (suggested for Qt-based environments, such as KDE, LXQt, etc.) and download the `.deb` package of your choice to the location of your choice.

   > [image: PeaZip deb packages]
3. Either double-click the downloaded `.deb` file and install the package using Ubuntu software or open a terminal, `cd` to the location where you downloaded the `.deb` package, and run:

   ```
   sudo apt install /path/to/peazip.deb
   ```

   Make sure to replace `/path/to/peazip.deb` with the actual path and filename.

To uninstall it along with its configuration files you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt purge peazip
```

**Method 2: Install PeaZip using Flatpak**

The downside of this method is that you have to go through some additional procedure to install Flatpak (if you haven't already). The benefit is that the package can be easily updated to a newer version by running in a terminal `flatpak update` (which by the way will also update all your other Flatpak apps) and you will also get access to the [Flathub](https://flathub.org/) repository (which is great in my opinion).

1. Install Flatpak by following the [official instructions for Ubuntu](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu).
2. Install PeaZip by running the following command:

   ```
   flatpak install flathub io.github.peazip.PeaZip
   ```

To uninstall it you can use the command:

```
flatpak uninstall io.github.peazip.PeaZip
```

Comment: Thank your for help

Comment: Peazip seems to be acting glitchy for me. Can it deal with Rar files? How can I uninstall PeaZip?

Comment: @Cool124 Please check my updated answer for the commands to uninstall PeaZip depending on the method you chose to install it.

Comment: @Cool124 According to https://peazip.github.io/, PeaZip can handle RAR files.

Comment: What if I had already installed PeaZip many weeks ago and so therefore i can't exactly remember how I installed it, is there a way to just purge it? PeaZip has been acting extremely glitchy for me, that's why I installed P7Zip because I can always count on P7Zip to work for me. I used P7Zip when I was on Windows it's always worked for me. Can I ask, what's your preferred  archiver for Linux?

Comment: @Cool124 +1 for pointing that out!  add that to your question (what have you tried) it will clear up some confusion :)

Comment: @Cool124 as you see, uninstalling depends on the installation method. You must know how you installed it in order to uninstall it. If you have flatpak installed, run `flatpak list` and see if PeaZip is listed there. If it is, it means you installed it this way and you can uninstall it with the flatpak command I provided. If it isn't there or of you don't use flatpak, run `apt list --installed` and see if it is listed there. Then use the `apt` command to uninstall it. As you are a new user, I guess you installed using one of these two ways, as building it from source would be much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Pea zip](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-linux.html) .deb file then
Open it by double click or right click and open to install it by Ubuntu Software App

or

```
sudo apt install the path/to/filename.deb
```